# actionscript 3 sectioned health bar

Tags: actionscript

I'm still new to actionscript so any help would be valuable. My game involves a Scottish bag piper being attacked by haggis, and each time he is hit, one heart should disappear (there will be three in total)

I've gotten it to work slightly with the first heart to disappear after the piper is hit by a haggis

```
piper.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, piper_damaged);
    function piper_damaged(event:Event):void {
        if (piper.hitTestObject(haggis)) {
            heart_one.visible = false;
            piper.gotoAndPlay(2);
                    }

    }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Is this game using timeline inside of Flash pro?

You could have a var that holds the number of hearts you want to display and each time there is a collisions then you can take away a heart until there are no hearts left.

var numberOfHearts:Number = 3;

piper.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, piper_damaged);
    function piper_damaged(event:Event):void {
        if (piper.hitTestObject(haggis)) {
            if(numberOfHearts > 0)
            {
               numberOfHearts--;
               trace(numberOfHearts);
            }
        }
    }

Aftre this would you need to set up your heart objects in an array and either make the one you took away not visible or a better way would be to remove it from the array altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I would have in my player class

```
public static var health:int = 0;
```

or something to that effect, have it start at 3, then run `health--;`

every time he was damaged. at that point, I'd have timer that checks for the value of the health variable every frame, and have the timer run a function that updates the graphics with each value of health.